# Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-aop

I am migrating my application from Spring 4.3.8 to Spring 5.1.5 using spring-boot 2.1.3.

Bean configuration for JMX enablement :

```
 <bean id="analytics.utility.mbeanServer" class="org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanServerFactoryBean">
        <property name="locateExistingServerIfPossible" value="true"/>
    </bean>

 <context:mbean-export server="analytics.utility.mbeanServer"/>
```

Build and install working fine, when application starts give below error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'analytics.utility.mbeanServer' while setting bean property 'server'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'analytics.utility.mbeanServer': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:378)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:110)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1665)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248)
    at com.ubs.f35.analytics.datait.rddh.ApplicationLauncher.main(ApplicationLauncher.java:28)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'analytics.utility.mbeanServer': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1674)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1233)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:257)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:367)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.AopConfigException: Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy.getProxy(CglibAopProxy.java:208)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactory.getProxy(ProxyFactory.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.createProxy(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:471)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.wrapIfNecessary(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:350)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.AbstractAutoProxyCreator.postProcessAfterInitialization(AbstractAutoProxyCreator.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:429)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.postProcessObjectFromFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1904)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:116)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer
```

This code was previously working fine with spring 4.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whats causing issue with xml based mbean intitialization, but able to make it work using Annotation based configuration.

@EnableMBeanExport with @Configuration which helped me out here.

Keeping this question open if someone finds the issue here.